# How to set image instead of default browser's blank screen on refresh

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I can change only the background color like that (default color is white):

```
html, body {
   height: 100%;
   background-color: rgba(79,63,50, 0.85);
}
```

but cannot set an image, for example:

```
html, body {
   height: 100%;
   background: url(../img/main/background.jpg) no-repeat 50% 0;
   background-size: cover;
}
```

Is it possible at all?

Plan B, could be to use an font-awesome's pre-loader symbol pre-loader, along with changed background color.

PS: The browser is Chrome. I'm using bootstrap with AngularJS. ng-cloak is used, also.

Comment: Your CSS should be fine using *background* for image, and the syntax seems right. Opening your console, you see any erros or connection erros? I think your file path is wrong.

Comment: The background image is set, but after short flash with default blank color - white.

Comment: Short flash? This happens to your entire application or some elements? It is possible that some configuration at your AngularJS be the responsible.

Comment: I meant, after refresh, for a short time background is white color, and after that background image appears. The problem is that I can only change this background color, but cannot set background image instead.

Comment: Could just be the browser choking on the image...what is the file size?

Comment: The size is 124k. May be I shall try with another image

Comment: Just reduced the image with quality loss to 30k. The result is the same.

Comment: You can use pattern image background, it will be really small in size, but background should has repeat attribute;